# Did I do this program correctly?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

Assignment is to Complete the 8 queens 2 dimensional array program with backtracking.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int b[8][8] = { 0 };
    int r, c, i;
    int count = 1;
    b[0][0] = 1;
    c = 0;

nextColumn:
    c++;
    if (c == 8)
        goto print;
    r =- 1;

nextRow:
    r++;
    if (r == 8)
        goto back;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (b[r][i] == 1)
            goto nextRow;
    }
    for (i = 0; (r - i) >= 0 && (c - i) >= 0; i++) {
        if (b[r - i][c - i] == 1)
            goto nextRow;
    }
    for (i = 0; (r + i) < 8 && (c - i) >= 0; i++) {
        if (b[r + i][c - i] == 1)
            goto nextRow;
    }
    b[r][c] = 1;
    goto nextColumn;
    c--;
    if (c == -1)
        return 0;
    r = 0;
    while (b[r][c] != 1)
        r++;
    b[r][c] = 0;
    goto nextRow;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Result No." << count << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (r = 0; r < 8; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++){
            cout << b [r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    count++;
    goto back;
}
```

Comment: Well, "does it generate the correct solutions" and "use backtracking"? (I am guessing something is "wrong" with the code.)

Comment: *gasp*, look at all those goto's ma!

Answer (score 5):

Well, no.

- Everything is one big function; it should be broken in to little functions
- The program -- like all programs -- should be self-testing.  There should be a function that returns `true` if the program worked and `false` if it didn't.
- You're using single-character variable names; variables should have meaningful names.
- You're writing to cout at every level; you should be performing calculations, returning results, then (optionally) printing results to cout.
- You're using `goto`, which is generally ConsideredHarmful.  And you're using it *a lot*, which is always ConsideredHarmful.

Comment: And not even a comment on the formatting (what formatting?), I admire your constraint ;-)

Comment: @Delan Azabani -- "Other than that, [Mrs. Lincoln](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Abraham_Lincoln), how did you enjoy the play?"  Whether a program produces the right answer at the moment rarely matters.  In the academic world (which is where I assume the OP is), it won't get him a good grade; in the professional world, you can't *tell* if it gets the right answer if the code's a mess, and if even if it does, the requirements will inevitably change over time and a poorly written program will quickly break.

Answer (score 3):

If you care about your program being correct, make sure it's readable first.

So properly indent the program, declare (and init) variables where you use them, and stop using the `goto` statement. There's `break` if you want to bail out early from a for loop. (Or better, write the loop code in a separate function and use early returns!).